# Subscription change from Subscription screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit, subscriptions

Now we grouped the subscription in the way that the user have possibility to downgrade/upgrade or cancel the current subscription from a Subscription Screen (settings/appleId/iTunes&AppStore..).

How to handle this case of user subscription change in app or on the server side ?

Comment: You just handle it the way you handle any subscription; through receipt validation and/or processing transactions on your payment queue. In the case of a downgrade the new product code will be presented at the next renewal. In the case of an upgrade the new product code appears immediately.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 I guess i should try on live , because I can't make purchase from subscription screen on sandbox

Answer (score 0):

In app:
You should get a callback in `SKPaymentObserver` with the new transaction. It will usually be with the same originalTransactionID.

Server:
Use server to server notification detailed here https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/news/45333106